# How to consistently scale down slider images that vary in width

Tags: html, css

How do i scale '.slick-slide img' by height. The 
images vary by width and so scaling the images by width would make them inconsistant porportionately.

When i try applying a dimension to a height property for '.slick-slide img' the images do not scale. Why does this not work when if i use a width property the images will scale?

https://jsfiddle.net/mbj7ckrs/8/

```
.slick-slide img{
 Display: block;

Margin-left: auto;
Margin-right auto;
Padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
    max-height: 10em;
}
```

When I apply this to the fiddle, all of the images appear to change size in a proportionate way.

Comment: i have tried apply a dimension to height but it will not scale. It will only scale if i use a width property which will not accomplish what i want to acheive because of the image dimensions. Any ideas as to why this is??

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'scale'? The images don't change size if you apply a max-height?

Comment: I would like to proportionatley decrease the size of the images. when i use a width property the decrease in size is not constistant as the images have varying width dimenions so how can i decrease the size consistantly for all image?